# Downloadable WPF Control that provide 3D Effects for vertical scrolling?

Tags: wpf, controls, download

Are there any WPF Control downloads that provide 3D effects for vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

[Open source project Thriple by Josh Smith](http://thriple.codeplex.com/) is a library of 3D controls and panels, for use in WPF applications. These reusable components make it easy to incorporate 3D in your user interfaces. Each component in the library is accompanied by sample applications, which allow you to experiment with them.

[image]